# How to exit out of the shell script with non zero status if the files are missing in both the machines?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I am running my below shell script from `machineA` which is copying the files from `machineB` and `machineC` into `machineA`. If the files are not there in `machineB`, then it should be there in `machineC`. Files won't be duplicated across `machineB` and `machineC`, they will have unique files so let's say I have total `100 files`, so it might be possible `40 files` are in `machineB` and remaining `60 files` will be in `machineC`.

I need to copy some files in `PRIMARY` directory in `machineA` and some files in `SECONDARY` directory in `machineA`.

Below is my shell script which works fine but I would like to handle some corner cases such as -

- In some cases suppose if the files are not available either in `machineB` or `machineC`, then I would like to exit out of the shell script with non zero status (which is unsuccessfull) and return the error with the file number that are not available in `machineB` and `machineC` both.

Below is my shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly PRIMARY=/test01/primary
readonly SECONDARY=/test02/secondary
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly LOCATION=/bat/test/pe_t1_snapshot

PRIMARY_PARTITION=(1003 1012 1031) # this will have more file numbers
SECONDARY_PARTITION=(1005 1032 1067)  # this will have more file numbers

dir1=/bat/test/pe_t1_snapshot/20140320
dir2=/bat/test/pe_t1_snapshot/20140320

if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ]
then

    # delete first and then copy the files in primary directory
    find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete
    for el in "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
    do
        scp user@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp user@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
    done

    # delete first and then copy the files in secondary directory   
    find "$SECONDARY" -mindepth 1 -delete
    for sl in "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}"
    do
        scp user@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$sl"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/. || scp user@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/t1_weekly_1680_"$sl"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/.
    done
fi
```

As I am calling the above shell script from the `Python subprocess` module -

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(shell_script, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, executable='/bin/bash')
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
if proc.returncode != 0:
    # log an error with message which file numbers are missing in machineB and machine
else:
    # log successfull status
```

In my above shell script I am using pipe `||` operator. If the files are not there in `machineB` then try in `machineC` using pipe `||` operator.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: could run `scp` from Python directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need get the file name and exist code, try this, you need set for secondary scp as well with different exist code, such as `exit 102`

```
# delete first and then copy the files in primary directory
    find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete
    for el in "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
    do
        if `scp user@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp user@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. ` ; then
            :
        else
            echo " scp is not successful on file $dir1/t1_weekly_1680_${el}_200003_5.data"
            exit 101
    done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Silly question - here 101 and 102 is the exit code? Correct? And what about which file numbers are missing? Can we get that information in `stderr` in Python script?

Comment: see my updates. You can use command `echo $?` to get the exit code

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> exit $?

or

> exit $LINENO

to get out of shell script with non success code.