# How to exit out of the shell script if the files are missng in both the machines?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scp

I am running my shell script on `machineA` which copies the files from `machineB` and `machineC` to `machineA`.

If the file is not there in `machineB`, then it should be there in `machineC` for sure. So I will try to copy from `machineB` first, if it is not there in `machineB` then I will go to `machineC` to copy the same files. Below is my shell script by which I am copying the files and `PRIMARY_PARTITION` is an array which has all the file numbers -

```
for el in "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
do
    scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@machineB:/te/data/te_snapshot/20140411/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@machineC:/te/data/te_snapshot/20140411/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.
done
```

Now the question is - There might be some cases, where the files are not there in both the machines - `machineB` and `machineC` then I would like to exit out of the shell script with non zero status and proper message with which file was missing -

So I did like this, I added another pipe statement at the end but somehow that message is not getting printed out on the screen.  And I am pretty much sure those files which is trying to copy are not there in those folders in those two machines -

```
scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@machineB:/te/data/te_snapshot/20140411/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@machineC:/te/data/te_snapshot/20140411/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || echo "File number $el missing on both the machines for primary partition." >&2; exit 1
```

So it should go to last  pipe statement and print it out on console. Right?

Is there anything wrong I did in my last pipe statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598310/how-to-exit-out-of-the-shell-script-with-non-zero-status-if-the-files-are-missin?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your solution it should work

`scp` returns 0 only when it succeeds. so you can write like this:

```
scp -q machineB:/path/to/your/file . || scp -q machineC:/path/to/your/file . || echo "Sorry no file found"
```

Now let first you check retrun code of each command like as follows

```
scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@machineB:/te/data/te_snapshot/20140411/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
      echo "No file found"
      exit 1
else
     echo "oh..file is here!"
fi
```

Same for second command. Now in both case if you get non zero value then your solution must work.